# Xcode: Is there a way to add a *run-phase* pre-action script? (hint: not a build-phase)

Tags: xcode

I can add a `build-phase script` to an `Xcode` C project but not a `run-phase pre-action script.`

I'd like to reset a test condition each time I run a program I'm debugging. The easiest way to do this is to run a shell script every time I run `(debug)` the program in Xcode. I can see the place to add this script in Xcode's "`edit scheme..."->"Run"->"Pre-actions"` setting, but that just displays `"No Actions"`.

I'm probably being stupid but I cannot see any way to add a `"script phase"` where the scheme currently shows `"No Actions"` in the scheme's `"Run" "Pre-actions"` section.

I guess I could try to remember to manually run a shell script from a terminal before chasing down a rabbit hole of debugging, but did I remember to set up that test condition each time I tried to chase the last rabbit?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this little plus sign is what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: And there it is... I need new glasses. Thank you so much.